Issue post deployment to azure using azure functions
facing issue with getting response post azure deployment successful, locally able to get results. Let me know anyone faced same (we are using nestjs and azure functions)
Able to verify from postman locally.
Post deployment response status we are getting 200 but response is not capturing in postman
Should be able to test postman from locally how response is coming in postman and post deployment also should be able verify from postamn

Retry the deployment of Azure function trigger by using VS Code Function extension and Azure function core tools command:-
Refer this Blog to deploy your nest.js Function properly.
VS Code:-

Azure Functions core tools command:-
az login
az account set --subscription "xxxxxxxon"
func azure functionapp publish siliconfunc4309


